# Is it possible to run a script when RSpec finishes a test

Tags: ruby, rspec

Ideally I'd like to be able to call one shell script if all the tests pass and a different one if they fail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/command-line/exit-status):

> The rspec command exits with an exit status of 0 if all examples pass,
>   and 1 if any examples fail.

So a small script like this should work:

```
if rspec
  ./success-script
else
  ./failure-script
fi
```

Comment: This is just what what I needed. I managed to pick up the exit code using $? and then test against that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just add an `after :suite` hook to your configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:suite) do
    # do whatever you need to do
  end
end
```

See [`before` and `after` hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) in the RSpec documentation.

Comment: To fully answer the question, you should give a small example of how to tell if the tests passed or failed.